PWA Action button is not working on mobile device
After installing the Progressive Web App (PWA) on my device, the incoming call notification appears as expected. However, the "Accept Call" button does not respond when tapped. Currently, I am focusing on making this feature compatible with mobile devices. It functions perfectly on desktop browsers, but I've encountered an issue on mobile. Busing (Node JS + PHP)
It should be work when we click on action button.
